# Two way removal of duplicate start and end nodes

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am just a beginner in python and this may seem like an easy fix but I have been stuck at it given my limited knowledge of python.

I have two lists that are paired together:

```
s = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,5,7]
t = [2,4,6,2,1,6,3,1,7,4,1]
```

This can be interpreted as start nodes and end nodes of lines, so 0 is connected to 2 and 1 is connected to 4 and so on.

I would like to remove all duplicate "lines" or pairs of nodes, in this example 7 -> 1 is repeated twice and 1 -> 4 is duplicated in the other direction 4 -> 1. I want to remove both types of duplicates and get the results:

```
S = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,3,5]
T = [2,4,6,2,6,3,1,7,4]
```

Preserving the order and pairs of start and end is required.

I hope this makes sense, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a nested for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a paired set and deduplicate the lists in order such as:

```
s = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,5,7]
t = [2,4,6,2,1,6,3,1,7,4,1]

seen=set()
li=[]
for t in zip(s,t):
    if frozenset(t) not in seen:
        li.append(t)
        seen.add(frosenset(t))
S,T=map(list,(zip(*li)))
```

Result:

```
>>> S
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5]
>>> T
[2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 3, 1, 7, 4]
```

Note: This *can* be reduced to:

```
seen=set()
S,T=zip(*[t for t in zip(s,t) if frozenset(t) not in seen and not seen.add(frozenset(t))])
```

But some will object to the use of a side effect in a list comprehension. I personally think it is OK in this use, but the loop form is considered by many to be better because it is far easier to read.

Comment: this code keeps the 1,4 and 4,1 and only removes the 7,1

Comment: Corrected with `frozenset`

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` these lists together and use `set` comprehension

```
u = {tuple({a,b}) for (a,b) in (zip(s,t))}

# u: {(0, 2), (1, 4), (1, 7), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 5), (5, 6)}

first, sec = zip(*u)

# first: (6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 7, 2)
# sec  : (2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0)
```

We use `tuple` to make objs hashable.

---

*Just notice that sets are unorded, so if order is important please highlight 
 that in your question.*

---

*To preserve orders, check @Dawg's answes. My solution for this case was very similar to his after he undeleted ;)*

Comment: Yes order is important, I apologize for not clarifying that in the beginning but yes the pairs of start and ends nodes need to be preserved in the correct order.

Comment: This code outputs:
a=[0,1,2,2,5,3,1,3,4]
b=[2,4,6,3,6,6,7,7,5]

I don't understand the randomness because some orders are preserved.

Comment: @mb567 oops, sorry. Edited